# How to load data in my Android app from online resource where I can add/update content easily?

Tags: android, database, online-storage

I want to update content/news in my app based on any online resource that's possible, a website, database or something similar where I can manually update/add content. The underlying purpose is to connect my app to that online resource, and reflect changes in my app content, whenever I update that online resource.

Right now I don't know what should be that online resource and how should I connect it with my app.

I would appreciate anyone coming up with any form of suggestions/solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating App Content means retrieving data which is stored on server in some database.

We can store and retrieve data or any content with the use of Web Services.

With the use of Web services you can parse the data and display it in your application.

You can also develop an Admin Panel for managing all your resources which will be then reflect to in your app.

These above things are possible using Networking libraries like **OkHTTP**, **Volly**, **Retrofit** etc. which gives you response in form of JSON (JavaScriptObjectNotation).

For Refrence Please visit :

1. OKHTTP > https://square.github.io/okhttp/
2. VOLLEY > https://developer.android.com/training/volley
3. RETROFIT > https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 1):

Lookup [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) library by Square. Super easy way to connect to an API. Then you can check out [rapidapi](http://rapidapi.com) website for a collection of APIs

Comment: Please make sure using comment section for two lines of answers. Avoid Giving answer for smaller content.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Api endpoint you can use Retrofit to get data. However if you dont then i belive you will need to make server using php and then connect to that server using Volley/OkHttp3 in order to get data.

Comment: Please use Comment section for the two or three lines of solution.